# gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer crashing

Tags: ios, iphone, uigesturerecognizer, nszombie

I have a gesture recognizer on my view controller which I use to slide in/out the navigation bar. Unfortunately there is a bad NSZombie that makes the whole app crash when I go swipe to go to the previous controller. It's very difficult to track because it only happens in a specific view controller.

Here is the error:

```
[MyViewController gestureRecognizer:shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

And here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pgr = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pgr:)];
    pgr.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pgr];
}

- (void)pgr:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    // Check if this is the first touch
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
        self.start = point.y;
    }

    CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
    self.currentX = point.x;
    self.offsetY = point.y - self.start;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: The relevant code is where you instantiate MyViewController. There you don't create a strong reference to it, so the viewController is deallocated prematurely.

Comment: I use Storyboard. How can I control allocation of view controllers?

Answer (score 1):

The delegate method is

```
- (BOOL)shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
```

Try to use

```
- (BOOL)shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if ([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: That's not a method from UIGestureRecognizerDelegate.... Just checked out in the header.

Comment: See Apple Docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-SW41